# C# Regular expression to match these strings

Tags: c#, regex

I have some strings of the following format:

```
--> ABCDEF_(0) "Abcde fgh"

--> GHIJ4 1
```

The first one should return 3 matches:

```
-->
ABCDEF_(0)
"Abcde fgh"
```

The second one should also return 3 matches:

```
-->
GHIJ4
1
```

So what I want to match is:

1. The arrow (-->)
2. Groups of non-whitespace, non-quote-surrounded characters
3. Expressions enclosed in quotes including their whitespace

There could conceivably more groups of type (2) and (3) in a string, so a single string could have more than just 3 matches.

So far this is what I have:

```
  var regex = new Regex(
      @"-->" + // match the starting arrow
      @"|[^""\s]*\S+[^""\s]*" + // match elements not surrounded by quotes, trimmed of surrounding whitespace
      @"|""[^""]+"""); // match elements surrounded by quotes
```

But this doesn't work because it breaks the expressions in quotes, returning for the first string:

```
-->
ABCDEF_(0)
"Abcde
fgh"
```

What regular expression would work? If there is a more simple method than regular expressions I would also accept it.

Comment: The 3rd part (1) of your second example doesn't have double-quotes around it, is that still supposed to match? If so, item 3 in your list of critieria needs amending.

Comment: @KazR 3rd part of 2nd example is supposed to match, and is covered by criterion #2. Criterion #3 is only for quote-surrounded items like 3rd part of 1st example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to an answer that got quickly deleted for some reason, I've managed to solve the problem.

Ideas:

- The first group "-->" is redundant
- Second and third group should be swapped.

Resulting regex:

```
Regex sWordMatch = new Regex(
      @"""[^""]*""" + // groups of characters enclosed in quotes
      @"|[^""\s]*\S+[^""\s]*", // groups of characters without whitespace not enclosed in quotes
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be easier to use captures (I've used named captures here):

```
var regex = new Regex(@"-->" // match the arrow
    + @"\s+(?<first>[^\s]+)" // capture the first part always unquoted
    + @"(\s+(?<second>(""[^""]+"")|[^\s]+))+"); // capture the second part, possibly quoted

var match = regex.Match("--> ABCDEF_(0) \"Abcde fgh\"");
Console.WriteLine(match.Groups["first"].Value);
Console.WriteLine(match.Groups["second"].Value);

match = regex.Match("--> GHIJ4 1");
Console.WriteLine(match.Groups["first"].Value);
Console.WriteLine(match.Groups["second"].Value);

match = regex.Match("--> GHIJ4 1 \"Test Something\" \"Another String With Spaces\" \"And yet another one\"");
Console.WriteLine(match.Groups["first"].Value);
Console.WriteLine("Total matches:" + match.Groups["second"].Captures.Count);
Console.WriteLine(match.Groups["second"].Captures[0].Value);
Console.WriteLine(match.Groups["second"].Captures[1].Value);
Console.WriteLine(match.Groups["second"].Captures[2].Value);
Console.WriteLine(match.Groups["second"].Captures[3].Value);
```

Comment: That's interesting, but there may be an arbitrary number of matches per line, not necessarily 3. A string could be for example "--> ABCDFEF 1 "ashe rer43" 3". I hadn't specified it, sorry, will add to the post.

Comment: Updated example to cater for multiple matches of the second group

Comment: It looks like that'd work, but it'd be somewhat unweildy. All I want is the collection of matches which I convert to a list of strings and send to some other method, so having to go through each group is a bit of a hassle. I've managed to answer my own question as well. Still, I wasn't aware of the technique, so thanks and upvoted. :)